# JAVA code failing to write to Excel through the List array declared

Tags: java, excel

My requirement is to read from a csv file and write to a excel file in each column with individual fields . I am successfully able to read from CSV file . But getting error on reading from the List array and writing to excel file. I am attaching code snippet with the error highlighted. Let me know the issue and if possible please send the fix and any sample code you have for the same functions.

The updated code package testmaven.testmv;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument.Iterator;

import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;
import org.apache.poi.hpsf.HPSFException;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class CSVReader {
    private static class Country {
        private String ip_address;
        private String full_ip_address;
        private String resource_name;
        private String serial_number;
        private String status;
        private String inactive;
        private String organistation;
        private String system_name;
        private String system_org;
        private String system_bus_crtcl;
        private String vlan_name;
        private String vlan_desc ;
        private String vlan_contact;
        private String class_1;
        private String family;
        private String assignee_zid;
        private String contact_applied;
        private String assignee_type;
        private String assignee_email_address;
        private String assignee_org_name;
        private String assignee_full_name;

        public Country(String ip_address, String full_ip_address, String resource_name,String serial_number, String status,String inactive,String organistation,String system_name,String system_org,String system_bus_crtcl,String vlan_name,String vlan_desc, String vlan_contact,String class_1,String family,String assignee_zid, String contact_applied,String assignee_type,String assignee_email_address,String assignee_org_name,String assignee_full_name) {
            this.ip_address = ip_address;
            this.full_ip_address = full_ip_address;
            this.resource_name = resource_name;
            this.serial_number = serial_number;
            this.status = status;
            this.inactive = inactive;
            this.organistation = organistation;
            this.system_name = system_name;
            this.system_org = system_org;
            this.system_bus_crtcl = system_bus_crtcl;
            this.vlan_name = vlan_name;
            this.vlan_desc = vlan_desc;
            this.vlan_contact = vlan_contact;
            this.class_1  = class_1 ;
            this.family = family;
            this.assignee_zid = assignee_zid;
            this.contact_applied = contact_applied;
            this.assignee_type = assignee_type;
            this.assignee_email_address = assignee_email_address;
            this.assignee_org_name = assignee_org_name;
            this.assignee_full_name = assignee_full_name;











        }


        /**
         * @return the ip_address
         */
        public String getIp_address() {
            return ip_address;
        }


        /**
         * @param ip_address the ip_address to set
         */
        public void setIp_address(String ip_address) {
            this.ip_address = ip_address;
        }


        /**
         * @return the full_ip_address
         */
        public String getFull_ip_address() {
            return full_ip_address;
        }


        /**
         * @param full_ip_address the full_ip_address to set
         */
        public void setFull_ip_address(String full_ip_address) {
            this.full_ip_address = full_ip_address;
        }


        /**
         * @return the resource_name
         */
        public String getResource_name() {
            return resource_name;
        }


        /**
         * @param resource_name the resource_name to set
         */
        public void setResource_name(String resource_name) {
            this.resource_name = resource_name;
        }


        /**
         * @return the serial_number
         */
        public String getSerial_number() {
            return serial_number;
        }


        /**
         * @param serial_number the serial_number to set
         */
        public void setSerial_number(String serial_number) {
            this.serial_number = serial_number;
        }


        /**
         * @return the status
         */
        public String getStatus() {
            return status;
        }


        /**
         * @param status the status to set
         */
        public void setStatus(String status) {
            this.status = status;
        }


        /**
         * @return the inactive
         */
        public String getInactive() {
            return inactive;
        }


        /**
         * @param inactive the inactive to set
         */
        public void setInactive(String inactive) {
            this.inactive = inactive;
        }


        /**
         * @return the organistation
         */
        public String getOrganistation() {
            return organistation;
        }


        /**
         * @param organistation the organistation to set
         */
        public void setOrganistation(String organistation) {
            this.organistation = organistation;
        }


        /**
         * @return the system_name
         */
        public String getSystem_name() {
            return system_name;
        }


        /**
         * @param system_name the system_name to set
         */
        public void setSystem_name(String system_name) {
            this.system_name = system_name;
        }


        /**
         * @return the system_org
         */
        public String getSystem_org() {
            return system_org;
        }


        /**
         * @param system_org the system_org to set
         */
        public void setSystem_org(String system_org) {
            this.system_org = system_org;
        }


        /**
         * @return the system_bus_crtcl
         */
        public String getSystem_bus_crtcl() {
            return system_bus_crtcl;
        }


        /**
         * @param system_bus_crtcl the system_bus_crtcl to set
         */
        public void setSystem_bus_crtcl(String system_bus_crtcl) {
            this.system_bus_crtcl = system_bus_crtcl;
        }


        /**
         * @return the vlan_name
         */
        public String getVlan_name() {
            return vlan_name;
        }


        /**
         * @param vlan_name the vlan_name to set
         */
        public void setVlan_name(String vlan_name) {
            this.vlan_name = vlan_name;
        }


        /**
         * @return the vlan_desc
         */
        public String getVlan_desc() {
            return vlan_desc;
        }


        /**
         * @param vlan_desc the vlan_desc to set
         */
        public void setVlan_desc(String vlan_desc) {
            this.vlan_desc = vlan_desc;
        }


        /**
         * @return the vlan_contact
         */
        public String getVlan_contact() {
            return vlan_contact;
        }


        /**
         * @param vlan_contact the vlan_contact to set
         */
        public void setVlan_contact(String vlan_contact) {
            this.vlan_contact = vlan_contact;
        }


        /**
         * @return the class_1
         */
        public String getClass_1() {
            return class_1;
        }


        /**
         * @param class_1 the class_1 to set
         */
        public void setClass_1(String class_1) {
            this.class_1 = class_1;
        }


        /**
         * @return the family
         */
        public String getFamily() {
            return family;
        }


        /**
         * @param family the family to set
         */
        public void setFamily(String family) {
            this.family = family;
        }


        /**
         * @return the assignee_zid
         */
        public String getAssignee_zid() {
            return assignee_zid;
        }


        /**
         * @param assignee_zid the assignee_zid to set
         */
        public void setAssignee_zid(String assignee_zid) {
            this.assignee_zid = assignee_zid;
        }


        /**
         * @return the contact_applied
         */
        public String getContact_applied() {
            return contact_applied;
        }


        /**
         * @param contact_applied the contact_applied to set
         */
        public void setContact_applied(String contact_applied) {
            this.contact_applied = contact_applied;
        }


        /**
         * @return the assignee_type
         */
        public String getAssignee_type() {
            return assignee_type;
        }


        /**
         * @param assignee_type the assignee_type to set
         */
        public void setAssignee_type(String assignee_type) {
            this.assignee_type = assignee_type;
        }


        /**
         * @return the assignee_email_address
         */
        public String getAssignee_email_address() {
            return assignee_email_address;
        }


        /**
         * @param assignee_email_address the assignee_email_address to set
         */
        public void setAssignee_email_address(String assignee_email_address) {
            this.assignee_email_address = assignee_email_address;
        }


        /**
         * @return the assignee_org_name
         */
        public String getAssignee_org_name() {
            return assignee_org_name;
        }


        /**
         * @param assignee_org_name the assignee_org_name to set
         */
        public void setAssignee_org_name(String assignee_org_name) {
            this.assignee_org_name = assignee_org_name;
        }


        /**
         * @return the assignee_full_name
         */
        public String getAssignee_full_name() {
            return assignee_full_name;
        }


        /**
         * @param assignee_full_name the assignee_full_name to set
         */
        public void setAssignee_full_name(String assignee_full_name) {
            this.assignee_full_name = assignee_full_name;
        }


        @Override
        public String toString() { // return "Country [name=" + name +
                                    // ", capital=" + capital + ", currency=" +
                                    // currency + "]";
            return this.ip_address + this.full_ip_address + this.resource_name + this.serial_number;
        }
    }

    public static <E> void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException,
            IOException {
        System.out
                .println("Reading from CSV file using BufferedReader and String Split");

        // List nation11 = readCSV();
        ArrayList<Country> nation11 = (ArrayList<CSVReader.Country>) readCSV();
        //System.out.println(nation11);

        int rowCount = 0;
        String excelFilePath = "D://abc.xls";
        Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
        Row row = sheet.createRow(++rowCount);
        // writeBook(aBook, row);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue("ip_address");

        cell = row.createCell(1);
        cell.setCellValue("full_ip_address");

        cell = row.createCell(2);
        cell.setCellValue("resource_name");

        cell = row.createCell(3);
        cell.setCellValue("serial_number");

        cell = row.createCell(4);
        cell.setCellValue("status");

        cell = row.createCell(5);
        cell.setCellValue("inactive");

        cell = row.createCell(6);
        cell.setCellValue("organistation");

        cell = row.createCell(7);
        cell.setCellValue("system_name");

        cell = row.createCell(8);
        cell.setCellValue("system_org");

        cell = row.createCell(9);
        cell.setCellValue("system_bus_crtcl");

        cell = row.createCell(10);
        cell.setCellValue("vlan_name");

        cell = row.createCell(11);
        cell.setCellValue("vlan_desc");

        cell = row.createCell(12);
        cell.setCellValue("vlan_contact");

        cell = row.createCell(13);
        cell.setCellValue("class_1");

        cell = row.createCell(14);
        cell.setCellValue("family");

        cell = row.createCell(15);
        cell.setCellValue("assignee_zid ");

        cell = row.createCell(16);
        cell.setCellValue("contact_applied");

        cell = row.createCell(17);
        cell.setCellValue("assignee_type");

        cell = row.createCell(18);
        cell.setCellValue("assignee_email_address");

        cell = row.createCell(19);
        cell.setCellValue("assignee_org_name");

        cell = row.createCell(20);
        cell.setCellValue("assignee_full_name");

        for (Country country : nation11) {

            row = sheet.createRow(++rowCount);
            // writeBook(aBook, row);
            cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue(country.ip_address);

            cell = row.createCell(1);
            cell.setCellValue(country.full_ip_address);

            cell = row.createCell(2);
            cell.setCellValue(country.resource_name);

            cell = row.createCell(3);
            cell.setCellValue(country.serial_number);

            cell = row.createCell(4);
            cell.setCellValue(country.status);

            cell = row.createCell(5);
            cell.setCellValue(country.inactive);

            cell = row.createCell(6);
            cell.setCellValue(country.organistation);

            cell = row.createCell(7);
            cell.setCellValue(country.system_name);

            cell = row.createCell(8);
            cell.setCellValue(country.system_org);

            cell = row.createCell(9);
            cell.setCellValue(country.system_bus_crtcl);

            cell = row.createCell(10);
            cell.setCellValue(country.vlan_name);

            cell = row.createCell(11);
            cell.setCellValue(country.vlan_desc);

            cell = row.createCell(12);
            cell.setCellValue(country.vlan_contact );

            cell = row.createCell(13);
            cell.setCellValue(country.class_1);

            cell = row.createCell(14);
            cell.setCellValue(country.family);

            cell = row.createCell(15);
            cell.setCellValue(country.assignee_zid);

            cell = row.createCell(16);
            cell.setCellValue(country.contact_applied);

            cell = row.createCell(17);
            cell.setCellValue(country.assignee_type);

            cell = row.createCell(18);
            cell.setCellValue(country.assignee_email_address);

            cell = row.createCell(19);
            cell.setCellValue(country.assignee_org_name);

            cell = row.createCell(20);
            cell.setCellValue(country.assignee_full_name);


        }

    //  ArrayList<Country> nation12 = nation11.replaceAll("\"","");     
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(excelFilePath);
    //  String abc = ((String) outputStream).replace("\""," ");

        workbook.write(outputStream);
    /*  FileWriter writer1 = null;
        writer1 = new FileWriter("D://abc.xls");*/

        /*BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D://abc.xls"));
        String newLine = " ";
        while ((newLine = br2.readLine()) != null && !newLine.isEmpty())

        {
            System.out.println(newLine);
            newLine = newLine.replace("\"", "");
    }*/
    }

    // }
    // parseCSV(); }

    public static List readCSV() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        List countries = new ArrayList<>();
        FileWriter writer = null;
        String line = " ";
        String oldContent = " ";
        String newContent = " ";
        // writer = new FileWriter("D://data1.csv");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D://data1.csv"));

        // System.out.println(br.readLine());
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && !line.isEmpty())

        {
        //  System.out.println(line);
            line = line.replace("|", ",");
            oldContent = oldContent + line + System.lineSeparator();

        //  System.out.println("after change " + line);
        //  System.out.println("after change OLD" + oldContent);
            // line.replaceAll("|",",");

        }
        //System.out.println("here am I " + oldContent);
        // newContent = oldContent.replaceAll("|",",");
        writer = new FileWriter("D://data1.csv");
        writer.write(oldContent);
        writer.close();
        // line= oldContent;
        // System.out.println(newContent);
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D://data1.csv"));
        line = " ";
        line = br1.readLine(); // Reading header, Ignoring
        //System.out.println("here am I again " + line);
        while ((line = br1.readLine()) != null && !line.isEmpty()) {
            String[] fields = line.split(",");
        //  System.out.println("fileds : " + fields[0]);

            String ip_address = fields[0];
        //  System.out.println("before removing double quotes : " + ip_address);

             ip_address = ip_address.replaceAll("\"", " ");
        //  System.out.println("after removing double quotes : " + ip_address);
            String full_ip_address = fields[1];
            full_ip_address = full_ip_address.replaceAll("\"", " ");
            String resource_name = fields[2];
            resource_name = resource_name.replaceAll("\"", " ");
            String serial_number = fields[3];
            serial_number = serial_number.replaceAll("\"", " "); 
            String status = fields[4];
            status = status.replaceAll("\"", " ");
            String inactive = fields[5];
            inactive = inactive.replaceAll("\"", " ");
            String organistation = fields[6];
            organistation = organistation.replaceAll("\"", " ");
            String system_name = fields[7];
            system_name = system_name.replaceAll("\"", " "); 
            String system_org = fields[8];
            system_org  = system_org.replaceAll("\"", " ");
            String system_bus_crtcl = fields[9];
            system_bus_crtcl = system_bus_crtcl.replaceAll("\"", " "); 
            String vlan_name = fields[10];
            vlan_name = vlan_name.replaceAll("\"", " ");
            String vlan_desc = fields[11];
            vlan_desc = vlan_desc.replaceAll("\"", " ");
            String vlan_contact = fields[12];
            vlan_contact =  vlan_contact.replaceAll("\"", " "); 
            String class_1 = fields[13];
            class_1 = class_1.replaceAll("\"", " ");
            String family = fields[14];
            family = family.replaceAll("\"", " ");
            String assignee_zid = fields[15];
            assignee_zid = assignee_zid.replaceAll("\"", " ");
            String contact_applied = fields[16];
            contact_applied = contact_applied.replaceAll("\"", " ");
            String assignee_type = fields[17];
            assignee_type = assignee_type.replaceAll("\"", " ");
            String assignee_email_address = fields[18];
            assignee_email_address = assignee_email_address.replaceAll("\"", " ");
            String assignee_org_name = fields[19];
            assignee_org_name = assignee_org_name.replaceAll("\"", " ");
            String assignee_full_name = fields[20];
            assignee_full_name = assignee_full_name.replaceAll("\"", " ");

            Country nation = new Country(ip_address, full_ip_address, resource_name, serial_number,status,inactive,organistation,system_name,system_org,system_bus_crtcl,vlan_name,vlan_desc,vlan_contact,class_1,family,assignee_zid,contact_applied,assignee_type,assignee_email_address,assignee_org_name,assignee_full_name );
            //System.out.println("am here : " + fields[1]);
            countries.add(nation);
        }
        br.close();

        return countries;
    }
}
```

When I enter 45k data the code is not producing any result without throwing any error. Can you advise.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0):

```
String excelFilePath = "D://abc.xlsx";
```

for.xlsx file you should use the

```
 XSSFWorkbook  wb = new XSSFWorkbook();  API
```

or change the extension to

```
String excelFilePath = "D://abc.xls";
```

& put the data on xls file

```
for (Country country : nation11) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(++rowCount);
            // writeBook(aBook, row);
            Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue(country.name);

            cell = row.createCell(1);
            cell.setCellValue(country.capital);

            cell = row.createCell(2);
            cell.setCellValue(country.currency);
        }
```

it works

Comment: no its not working , getting error : Type mismatch : cannot convert from element type Object to CSVReader.Country..Please advise

Comment: typecast List to ArrayList  `ArrayList<Country> nation11 = (ArrayList<CSVReader.Country>)readCSV();`